# CSS Line Height / H1 Font Size

Tags: css, html

I am not really sure what is causing the `line-height` to display differently in every browser.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to fix it?

```css
body {
  font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
} 

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

h1 {
   font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:18px">This is a textbox</span>
</h1>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is any help to you,but i remember reading about this awhile ago,it has something to do that browsers understand pixels differently try playing around with the height and pre-fixses webkit,moz etc etc

Comment: both latest FF and Chrome give me the 1st result. you need to give more info on which browsers its giving each results.

Answer (score 4):

It's because your `h1` element is using browser-default `font-size` itself which you aren't accounting for. For instance, in Chrome, the `h1` element has a default `font-size` of `2em` - which is larger than the `18px` on your `span` element. If the `h1` element's `font-size` is *smaller* than `18px` by default, the overall height of your `h1` element will be `25px`.

To avoid this, we can set the `h1` element's `font-size` to `initial`:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: initial;
}
```